# "put on hold" question also locked

Tags: discussion

This question was put on hold and more information is asked for:

[Contextual filter: Content: Nid issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/284555/contextual-filter-content-nid-issue)

But the question also seems to be locked, so it can't be edited or commented on, new information can't be provided!

I don't know of the author has this ability (to edit it), but I also don't see what they might add to the question as it doesn't seem unclear to me.

From what I can gather he has simply hit the `maxlength=128` character limit set on that input field.

Can this question be reopened and unlocked?

Comment: Indeed! I couldn't even flag it to be reopened if I wanted. Buttons/options missing. But comments would be nice.

Comment: The question has been migrated from another site, and since it has been closed as off-topic on _Drupal Answers_, it is locked.

Comment: So how can it be unlocked then? And I think it should be reopened since it isn't off-topic. But I can't do anything towards reopening it, because it's locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lock is automatic (when a migrated post is closed), but I'm inclined to agree that it seems clear enough what the OP is asking for help with.

I've rewritten it to (hopefully) remove any ambiguity, and unlocked and reopened.